# Can I use curl to get the server's private key?

Tags: security, ssl

I'm trying to analyze an HTTPS connection with Wireshark. To do this, I need the server's private key. Is there a way to download the private key using curl, or some other tool?

```
curl https://user:pass@example.com
??? https://user:pass@example.com --output-to-file key.txt
```

Comment: Even if you could get the server privatekey -- which as answered you almost certainly can't -- it can decrypt an SSL/TLS capture only if 'plain RSA' keyexchange was used; this used to be common but after Snowden many admins and server and client/browset developers made more efforts to move to DHE and ECDHE keyexchanges (also called PFS) which are now widely supported, usually preferred, and sometimes required. Wireshark can decrypt these if and _only_ if you obtained the per-session premaster or master secret from either endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the server explicitly offers the private key for download (which would be foolish) you cannot get the private key since, as it name suggests, this key is intended to be kept private. Especially you cannot extract the key from a HTTPS connection since the key is only used to protect the connection but not send inside the connection. If this would be the case and anybody could get the key which is protecting the connection than the security offered by HTTPS would obviously be broken.

For more details about this I recommend that you study the concepts behind [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) and [how SSL/TLS works](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work).